# Detect wifi and network connectivity in midp

Tags: java, java-me, midp, j2mepolish, midp-2.0

Is it possible to detect that a phone has network connectivity and/or wifi using midp ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just making a connection and see if it throws an exception.

Comment: That does'nt work, where I try and send an SMS no exception is thrown.